# Evaluate code once the view is rendered in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In rails I've built a sort of cronjob, but once the view is rendered there some code I would like to run like a 'signoff' on the task processed.

Where would I put code so that it is run at the absolute end of processing (once the view is rendered)

How does rails process html does it buffer? (Would it flush HTML to the user as its rendered or once its rendered?)

Comment: Yes, you grab the rendered result if you inject a middleware at the bottom of the stack. The response contains the `html`.

Comment: How would I implement it in the controller? After `format.html` (If its there - its not always present in all controllers)

Comment: Does this action need to be able to prevent rendering, or is it administrative?  If you don't need this code to prevent the view from rendering, you can use an `after_filter` on the controller...

Comment: Your middleware might still change the html output, so it's risky to do it in the controller.

Comment: The cron needs the html output at the end its just a number like 4000 for 4000 items processed, once its done it just has to sign off in the db 4000 items are done, but shouldn't if it times out.. hence the reason to do it at the end (it hardly times out but its a safety measure)

Answer (score 1):

You can render the view to a string, catch any Timeouts that could happen while rendering, log the results of the action, and return the string:

```
begin
  @elements = Element.find(:all)
  html = render_to_string
  # Store the result
  Result.create(:element_count => @elements.count)
rescue Timeout::Error
  # Store the result of the call as failed?
  Result.create(:element_count => 0)
end
send_data html, :disposition => 'inline', :type => 'text/html'
```

Some other things that you can do to achieve your goal could be:

1. You can use a rake task instead of a controller action, if the code that you need to execute is only triggered by your cron job.
2. Instead of directly making a request using wget in your cron job, you can call a script that will make a request to your controller, inspect the output of the request, and then log the result (maybe by calling a new action in the controller).

Answer (score 0):

To pick an element from the rendered HTML, you could read the value using javascript/JQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        var completion = $('#items_processed').val();  
     });
```

Comment: Im running it as a cron task so its wget calling im not too sure it will process javascript.